# Refer to Own Property With Object Type Alias

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an object type alias like so:

```
type PropsType = {
  options: string[];
  display: object;
}
```

How would I redefine the display property to have the values of `options` as the key? How can one property refer to another inside the same type definition?

### EDIT:

I am converting an existing React component to Typescript. The component is a custom select box (dropdown menu). Ordinarily, it will simply present the array of options to the user. But in situations where the options are more 'cryptic', a `display` option can be used. The `display` object uses each entry in `options` as a key and the display string as the value.
**Example:**

```
<ChoiceBox 
  options={[12345abcDEF, 3jijskjfkdjs, kpofkjspklkds]} 
  display={{12345abcDEF: "Fish", 3jijskjfkdjs: "Frog", kpofkjspklkds: "Pie" }} 
/>
```

Inside the `ChoiceBox` component, the output is rendered like so:

```
<div>{display ? display[option] : option}</div>
```

Comment: @jcalz it’s supposed to be an object.

Comment: Can you give examples?  What is "the key" there?

Comment: I think once I understand what you're looking for, the answer will be "there is no specific type that works this way but you can make a generic type that acts as a constraint"... *maybe* like `type PropsType<T extends object> = {display: T, options: Array<keyof T>}`, but without more details of the use case (examples of acceptable/unacceptable values and how you intend to use them) I can't be sure.

Comment: That’s where I was going with it originally, using a generic but I kept getting an error.

Comment: @jcalz current use case (as I'm converting an existing script to Typescript): the options are for a dropdown box. However in cases where the options are 'cryptic' like an alphanumeric ID, a display object may be provided and it just uses the option as the key. So "12345abcDEF" will be displayed as "Apple Pie" or something.

Comment: Could you [edit] to put your [mre] in the question?  Code is better than an English description, and "I kept getting an error" isn't enough information for me to proceed.  If you can make it so that the code demonstrates what you're doing when pasted into another IDE, then it'll be easier for others to help you.

Comment: @jcalz I have edited the original post.

Comment: Your [mre] looks like [invalid JSX to me](https://tsplay.dev/WyqDxW). Could you please fix it?  Ideally I could paste your code into my own IDE and... oof, I'm repeating myself.  How should we proceed here?